# Issue provisioning IIS 7.5 server using Web Farm Framework 2

Tags: iis-7.5, web-farm-framework

We are getting the following error when trying to provision a secondary server:

[image]

We did have DFS-R services installed, and as suggested in this [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Microsoft_IIS/Q_26958758.html), we removed them, but no luck..